How to make compilation single threaded in QMake?
I know that you can add -j1 flag to make, but how can you do it in QMake?
Long time ago there was a variable MAKEFLAGS but now there're hundreds of different variables instead:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html
I tried to add this flag to QMAKE_LFLAGS, to QMAKE_CXXFLAGS and so on, it didn't help, I still got this line in compile output

15:23:29: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" -j2


Are you talking about QMake as used by Qt Creator?  Because to the best of my knowledge, qmake itself, the command-line tool, stops at creating makefiles (by default) or IDE project files.  It doesn't run make.

@JohnBollinger , yes, you are right

QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS *= .NOTPARALLEL in order to enable single threaded builds per .pro file.
Not well documented but you can find it here: https://github.com/qt-labs/jom/blob/master/changelog.txt

If you are using Qt Creator you can configure this in

Projects > Build settings > Build steps > Make > Parallel jobs

Choose how much you need and it will change -j2 to -j1 etc.
